# Optimality of Maximum-Likelihood function for a mixture of two binomial distributions

Tags: r, estimation, maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution

This is an extension of an earlier question asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327702/finding-an-estimator-for-parameter-n-for-a-mix-of-two-binomially-distributed-p?noredirect=1#comment621121_327702). I have a data-set coming from a distribution given by:

$$Pr(X=k)=p \left({n\choose k}a^k(1-a)^{n-k}\right)+(1-p) \left({n\choose k}b^k(1-b)^{n-k}\right)$$

which is a mixture of two binomial distributions.

My aim is to estimate the parameter values, namely: n, p, a, b. To this I want to optimize the maximum likelihood function using "JDEoptim" package via R software.

```
fn<-function(x){
  #x(1)=p; x(2)=n; x(3)=a; x(4)=b;
  -prod(DensityFn(x, dataset[1:length(dataset)]))
}

DensityFn<-function(x, val){
  x[1]*dbinom(val, floor(x[2]), x[3])+(1-x[1])*dbinom(val, floor(x[2]), x[4])
}

lower=c(0, 11, 0, 0);
upper=c(0.5, 20, 1, 1);

print(JDEoptim(lower, upper, fn))
```

The variable "data-set" contains the values generated by this density function.
The output upon running this program gives me:

```
$par [1]  0.07007818 11.85238114  0.86411002  0.64941201

$value [1] 0

$iter [1] 0

$convergence [1] 0
```

'iter' is 0 while 'convergence' is 0...indicating convergence has occured, however the parameter values outputted are far off from the actual values.
Also, every time I run the program, the parameter estimates differ, but 'iter' and 'convergence' are always 0.

Is my code and logic correct?

Comment: At minimum, you should provide a link to your earlier question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327702/finding-an-estimator-for-parameter-n-for-a-mix-of-two-binomially-distributed-p?noredirect=1#comment621121_327702

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Is it usually bad practice to ask follow-up questions within a short time-frame to an already answered question? I'm asking because I'm a relatively new user to the stack community

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem by using log-likelihood instead.

used

```
-sum(log(DensityFn(x, dataset[1:length(dataset)])))
```

instead of

```
-prod(DensityFn(x, dataset[1:length(dataset)]))
```